# Generate SQL string using schema.CreateTable fails with postgresql ARRAY

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis

I'd like to generate the verbatim CREATE TABLE .sql string from a sqlalchemy class containing a postgresql ARRAY.

The following works fine without the ARRAY column:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy import *
from geoalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

metadata=MetaData(schema='refineries')

Base=declarative_base(metadata)

class woodUsers (Base):
    __tablename__='gquery_wood'
    id=Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=Column('name', String)
    addr=Column('address', String)
    jsn=Column('json', String)
    geom=GeometryColumn('geom', Point(2))
```

this woks just as i'd like it to:

```
In [1]: from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
In [3]: tab=woodUsers()

In [4]: str(CreateTable(tab.metadata.tables['gquery_wood']))
Out[4]: '\nCREATE TABLE gquery_wood (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tname VARCHAR,      \n\taddress VARCHAR, \n\tjson VARCHAR, \n\tgeom POINT, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id)\n)\n\n'
```

however when I add a postgresql ARRAY column in it fails:

```
class woodUsers (Base):
    __tablename__='gquery_wood'
    id=Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=Column('name', String)
    addr=Column('address', String)
    types=Column('type', ARRAY(String))
    jsn=Column('json', String)
    geom=GeometryColumn('geom', Point(2))
```

the same commands as above result in a long traceback string ending in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.pyc in _compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     70             getter = operator.attrgetter("visit_%s" % visit_name)
     71             def _compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw):
---> 72                 return getter(visitor)(self, **kw)
     73         else:
     74             # The optimization opportunity is lost for this case because the

AttributeError: 'GenericTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_ARRAY'
```

If the full traceback is useful, let me know and I will post.

I think this has to do with specifying a dialect for the compiler (?) but im not sure. I'd really like to be able to generate the sql without having to create an engine. I'm not sure if this is possible though, thanks in avance.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a complicated solution that involves digging in sqlalchemy.dialects.
You should first try it with an engine though. Fill in a bogus connection url and just don't call connect().

Comment: tried adding an engine this way: `engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase');
metadata=MetaData(engine, schema='refineries') `  the result is the same error as above. Maybe im not adding the engine correctly? Apologies if so.

Comment: I'd use bind=engine to be explicit, but you did it the right way.

Comment: still no luck. same response as above. can anyone suggest an alternative?